# jQuery selector based on css/tag type

Tags: jquery

I want to select an li element based on its id and class :

```
var selector = $('#myId myCss');
```

or just based on li :

```
var selector = $('#myId li.myCss');
```

Is my syntax correct ?

Comment: there is no point in selecting ID then class. because the selector with ID will always (and should ) return only one element.

Comment: It seems you're after `$('#myId.myCss');` or `$('li#myId.myCss');`

Comment: @Shyju: To be fair, it's useful in *some* circumstances; if you use the same `.js` file across multiple pages, you can use this approach to target specific elements with the same ID (but on different) pages.

Comment: @Matt ~ that's actually a valid point. huh. never occurred to me before, probably because I tend to favor positioning over `#id.class`-ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is doesnt't make sense to select on ID and class and HTML tag type. I suggest you do write

```
var selector = $('#myId');
```

or

```
var selector = $('li.myCss');
```

Comment: Why `$('li.myCss[id="myId"]');` over `$('li#myId.myCss');`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var selector = $('#myId myCss');
```

Selects all elements with tagname 'myCss' (<myCss>) inside any element with id 'myId'

```
var selector = $('#myId.myCss');
```

Selects all elements with both id myId and class myCss.

```
var selector = $('li#myId.myCss');
```

Selects all li elements with both id myId and class myCss, usually not required as we use id usinquely, can be useful when differentiating elements with same class.

I dont understand what is confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
var selector = $('#myId.myCss');
```

if you've done your CSS correctly then it will assign a style based on your class.